# After upgrading from Android gradle plugin version 3.6.4 to 4.2.1 i got attrs.xml:11:4: Invalid value 'null' for <enum>

Tags: android, xml, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I tried to upgrade my Android projects targetSdkVersion from 30 to 31
Therefore i upgraded Android gradle plugin 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4' to
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'

gradle version is 6.7.1

i got
.../app/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml:11:4: Invalid value 'null' for . Must be an integer. (--scan option)

error message start `Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDemoDebugResources'.`

here is my attrs.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="GlobalStyleable">
        <attr name="title" format="string" />
        <attr name="text" format="string" />
        <attr name="description" format="string" />
        <attr name="enabled" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="actionText" format="string" />
        <attr name="endIcon" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
 
    <declare-styleable name="SimpleEditText">
        <attr name="android:enabled" />
        <attr name="title" />
        <attr name="text" />
        <attr name="description" />
        <attr name="error" format="string" />
        <attr name="endIconMode" />
        <attr name="endIconDrawable" />
        <attr name="inputType" format="enum">
            <enum name="text" value="0x00000001" />
            <enum name="password" value="0x00000081" />
            <enum name="passwordWithoutKeyboard" value="0x00000081" />
            <enum name="number" value="0x00000002" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="contextMenu" format="enum">
            <enum name="full" value="0" />
            <enum name="onlyCopy" value="1" />
            <enum name="onlyPaste" value="2" />
            <enum name="none" value="3" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="mask" format="enum">
            <enum name="phone" value="0" />
            <enum name="card" value="1" />
            <enum name="bin" value="2" />
            <enum name="account" value="3" />
            <enum name="symbol2" value="4" />
            <enum name="symbol3" value="5 " />
            <enum name="smsCode" value="6" />
            <enum name="password" value="7" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
 
    <declare-styleable name="SimpleEditTextWithStartDrawable">
        <attr name="android:enabled" />
        <attr name="title" />
        <attr name="text" />
        <attr name="description" />
        <attr name="error" />
        <attr name="endIconMode" />
        <attr name="endIconDrawable" />
        <attr name="inputType" />
        <attr name="contextMenu" />
        <attr name="mask" />
    </declare-styleable>
 
    <declare-styleable name="ProgressButton">
        <attr name="android:text" />
        <attr name="loading" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

please help

Comment: TRY CLEANING THE PROJECT

Comment: Already tried it